# Set caret position in javafx.scene.control.TextArea and javafx.scene.control.TextField

Tags: javafx-2

I need to set the caret position manually in my code.
There is a `getCaretPosition()` under `javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl` but there is no setter method.

How can I set the caret position?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
ta.setText("1234567890");
ta.positionCaret(4);
```

Comment: positionCaret()... what a confusing name for that method.

Comment: yep, smth like `setCaretPosition` would be convenient

Comment: There's pretty strange behaviour in TextArea, like the down arrow doesn't move down.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the positionCaret function as mentioned before. But make sure to wrap it in Platform.runLater. Otherwise it might not work at all.

```
Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textArea.positionCaret( 0 );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two method in TextInputControl that allow manipulation of caret position. 
These are :-

1. **selectPositionCaret(int pos)** - Selects the text between the last caret position up to the current caret position that you entered.
2. **positionCaret(int pos)** - Sets the current caret position clearing the previous selection as well.

So i think in your case you want to use the positionCaret method to set the position without any selections.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add it at the end of your TextField you can do the next

```
TextFieldName.positionCaret(TextFieldName.getText().length());
```

this will add the Curser at The end .